# How To Limit User RAM and CPU

Tags: cpu-load, ulimit, cgroup, resource-limiting, cpulimit

So this is my first time posting on Ubuntu forums, so please excuse me if this question is repetitive, or just plain stupid.

A bit of background: I am a 14yr old developer, who has an ubuntu 20.04 server. I started a small hosting service and we racked up quite a bit of clients. Now, we have a pricing model, like certian users can only get 1vCPU and 4GB Ram, while other users can have 6vCPUs and 20GB Ram For $80 Per 6 Months.

My Problem: I cannot limit how many vCPUs and RAM a user can get. I tried programs like cgroups, but when I checked how much ram a user had by `free -m`, the server returned to me 24GB (How Much Memory On The VM).

My Question: Is there a proper way to limit a **specific user's** RAM and vCPU usage? Preferably, if you could give me a guide that would be perfect! Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Making Some Progress: With cgroup, I can limit a specific user's CPU usage (/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-USERID.slice). In here, I can edit the cpu.cfs_quota_us, but this only limits CPU Percentage. Also a weird thing for me, when I do cat cpu.cfs_quota_us I get 200000? Isnt that 200%? I thought the default value for max was 101000?
Still my main question is, how can I limit each user's core count, and memory?

More Progress: according to [redhatguideforcgroup](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01) instead of using the cpu directory, the cpuset directory manages **Multicore** which is what I think I need.

Now IK I am getting close. While in the /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset DIR I can run cat cpuset.cpus and that returns to me 0-5 (which is all the 6 cores I have present on my VM). Now if someone who knows basic cgroups (v2) can help me out to how I can set that to a specific user, I would appreciate that. [this helped me](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html)

Comment: Have you considered using a job scheduler such as SLURM?

Comment: @Ray That Looks Promising, however, since I offer hosting, my clients need to be able to SSH into their made user.

Comment: This isn't Ubuntu Forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/) so is there a reason why you're mentioning the Ubuntu Forums?

Comment: My bad, is this the wrong location for this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a Q&A site for Ubuntu and its official flavors, and your question is certainly on topic on this site. Ubuntu Forums is another website.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. I am looking at cgroup again, is it possible to limit a specific user's usage with that? Currently looking at [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7mgaWqiV90)

Comment: If you'd edited your question to remove reference to the other UF site, I'd have removed my comment :)

Comment: At this point, I am not sure what programs to use or not. It seems like cgroups is good, and I found a tutorial to limit total CPU %, but not total CPU Core Count.

Comment: Does each user have a VM allocated to them?   I believe SLURM supports VMs, but I don't know how to do that.  But yes, they will ssh into your server and submit jobs.  You should try configuring it -- that's probably the best way to understand what a job scheduler (i.e., SLURM isn't the only one out there) does.

Comment: @Ray No, multiple users share 1 VM, but I will checkout SLURM out!